# Laravel Application becomes slow after few weeks in Digitalocean Droplet and htop shows mysql consuming high memory

Tags: mysql, laravel, apache, digital-ocean, ubuntu-20.04

I have a LAMP (ubuntu 20.04, MySQL ver 8.0.27)  Droplet with 4GB memory/80GB Disk and hosted 6 subdomains with 6 client DB (each client has their own codebase and DB). During the first weeks the Application CRUD was way faster than local machine but as more subdomain added, the server has become slow. An insert/save takes around 8 seconds.

Disabling performance_schema at `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` doesn't made much difference and when `skip-name-resolve=1` added to my.cnf , I can't login  to application.

Running mysqltuner shows the message

> Configure your accounts with IP or subnet only, then update your configuration with skip-name-resolve=1

and htop output shows mysql taking 17.6% of memory.

Have tried multiple option but couldn't solve and as already server is live.

I have hosted application with 6 subdomains like c1.domain.com, c2.domain.com c3. in single server/Droplet. is this the right approach?

.ENV :

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:nuq9fD+0DGBdcSK+1n2uu2EoByQvIxZEJo8GzvVVdGs=
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_URL=http://localhost
LOG_CHANNEL=stack
SESSION_DOMAIN=c1.domain.com
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=c1.domain.com

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=testDB
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=Test@123
```

HTOP

[image]

MySqlTuner

[image]

Comment: What SQL is involved in an `INSERT/SAVE`?  Do `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` during it.

Comment: Additional information request, please. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
AND very helpful OS information, includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.